# How to replace all images within exported xml files to demo.jpg?

Tags: images, export, xml

I'm going to create a demo data by exporting a site (Wordpress Export Tool) and get an xml file.

I don't want my users who import my xml and get all actual images of the site.

Is it possible (in not manual way) to make replace all images with my dummy.jpg image?

Is there any plugin to help work on this?

Comment: Why can't you simply do a search, find and replace using a tool like Notepad++?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic, you can do this by writing your own code.

Comment: @BradDalton I'm not sure you understand my question clearly.
How can you really use that tool when path of images are in various patterns? (e.g. contain /upload/2014/..., /upload/2015 as well as various images with different sizes : thumbnail, full, etc. )

Comment: @Wyck Why are plugin recommendations off-topic? It's strange!
I saw tons of people answer questions and recommend using jquery plugins in stack overflow. They are illegal. lol

Comment: Plugin recommendations were on topic until the community decided to make it off topic. Please read the tag description for the tag 'plugin-recommendation`